# Java garbage collection : what is virtual space in parallel collector?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, heap-memory

I am aware of various spaces in memory during life cycle of java objects. `YougGen ( Eden, Survior space), Tenured (Old gen) and PermGen spaces.`

But as per latest oracle [article](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/parallel.html#CHDCFBIF), I have encountered one more space : ***virtual*** as per below image in parallel collector. I did not find any information in that article about "`virtual`" space.

[image]

***What is the significance of*** "***`virtual`***" ***space? Any idea?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtual is unused memory. Virtual = MaxYoungSize - YoungSize